# about exchange the order of double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How can I exchange the order of the double integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sin x}f(x,y)dydx$$
My attempt : I think maybe I can use the function arcsinx but the function’s domain is
[-1,1] I think maybe I should translation and rotation the function

Comment: Here you can exchange it freely while you sure that the function is integrable. (As none of the bounds of the integral depend on one of the variables.)

Comment: Aaaaaaa sorry I tap wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition the interval for $x$ into $[0,\pi/2), [\pi/2,3\pi/2) $ and $[3\pi/2,2\pi)$ giving you a sum of three integrals.

Exchange the order of integration for each of these using three versions of $\arcsin$ that map to the appropriate Interval.

Comment: Can you teach me what should I do such like [$\pi$/2,3$\pi$/2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

$$
\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x} \color{red}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm d}y} ~ f(x,y) = \color{red}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm d}y} \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x} ~ f(x,y)
$$